# Extract field embedded in log data

Tags: splunk, splunk-formula

I want to extract a field from a string in Splunk. Here's an example piece of data, from which I want to extract the `vin` field.

```
  {"timestamp":"2147483647","time":"2019-07-12T07:12:30Z","source_type":"APP/PROC/WEB","source_instance":"3","origin":"rep","msg":"2019-07-12 07:12:30.840  INFO 15 --- [ XNIO-2 task-95] f.c.g.m.c.m.r.r.GetCurrentLiteController : {\"transaction_summary\":{\"vin\":\"3FA6P0LU8JR126702\",\"service\":\"moduleinfo\",\"api_call\":\"getcurrentlite\",\"requesting_system\":\"CVFMA\",\"start_time\":\"1562915550829\",\"end_time\":\"1562915550840\",\"response_time\":\"11\",\"http_response_code\":\"200\",\"app_status_code\":\"200\",\"trace_id\":\"62b2e776-fd02-44c1-8f49-01930fc667db\",\"userid\":\"GVMS\",\"x_b3_traceid\":null,\"x_b3_spanid\":null,\"x_span_export\":\"true\"}}","message_type":"OUT","level":"info","job_index":"0bfbe359-fe76-43e0-9a19-cea5dfd80856","job":"diego_cell","ip":"10.68.80.94","event_type":"LogMessage","cf_space_name":"Ford-GVMS_ECC_PROD","cf_org_name":"Ford-GVMS_FMCC_PROD_ECC_Prod","cf_app_name":"gvms-moduleinfo-api"}
```

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Please add your code to question.

Comment: Tried with this | rex field=msg "vin..?<vin>[^\"]+"  code

Comment: Improve question. There's not a separate program for Splunk.

Answer (score 0):

See [the help documentation for your version of Splunk](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.6.12/SearchReference/Rex) for the exact details. I think you want something like:

```
| rex "vin\\\":\\\"<(?<vin>[^\"]+)"
```

The exact solution will depend on what has actually been escaped. If the data really has all the escaped quotation marks as your example, what I have above may work. When I've done something like this, I've usually started with a regex that captures more than I want, then move the match forwards a bit and then determine the stopping point. For instance, You could start with

```
| rex "vin<(?<bigvin>.*)>
```

To see that you're really on the right track. Then start adding characters before the capturing part until you're capturing something that starts with `3F` (in your example). Then you should be able to replace the `.*` with `[\"]+` and get what you want.